# Clearing objects that are floated inside list items

Tags: css

I have a list item, with floated objects *inside* of each item.

html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="icon" /><div class="text">blah</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="icon" /><div class="text">blah</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.icon, .text { float: left; }
.text:after { clear: both; }
```

My understanding is that the second style should add a clear: both *after* the text box. But it doesn't appear to be the case.

Normally, I would add an extra DIV after the .text div which had a class of 'cleared' or something to that affect which would clear the objects, but I have noticed many people don't do that and simply use the `:after` selector, equating to less hacky code.

Any pointers on what I am missing on how this works? Cheers

Comment: In my code they aren't self closing, I just did them for pseudo reasons here. But I didn't know that Css3 uses double colons! Thanks for that!